# Como clonar um repositório git (BARE) de uma pasta do windows7 para o UBUNTU16.04?

Tags: linux, windows, git

O meu sistema host é o windows7 e tenho um sistema guest em virtualBox, Ubuntu 16.04.

Compartilhei uma pasta no win7 (**sf_AA_SHARE_FOLDER**) para dentro do linux e dentro dela possuo uma outra pasta que se chama **CHM_FINAL_BARE** que é de onde desejo clonar os arquivos.

Como se pode ver na foto abaixo, eu fiz um clone para dentro da minha pasta `vhosts/chm.test` no meu home no linux usando o comando de sempre: `git clone "/home/....." chm.test`

Ao fim do processo eu recebo uma mensagem dizendo que o gist clonou um repositório vazio e isso não é verdade, ver foto.

Em seguida tentei abrir o gitk de dentro desse repositório bare (como sempre faço) e recebi uma mensagem de erro que não pode achar o HEAD, o que geralmente acontece quando a pasta está vazia.

Ou seja, parece que o git do linux não está conseguindo enxergar o que tem dentro da pasta do windows7.

Alguém pode dizer como clonar esse repositório, se é que é possível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou fazer um *commit* antes? `git commit -m "foo bar"`

Comment: Oi zekk, nesse caso não precisa de commit. Essa é a clonagem inical de um repositório BARE. Deveria vir algo de lá.

Comment: É... parece que tem ago errado com o deretório BARE mesmo. Tentei clonar de dentro do win7 para uma outra pasta e tive o mesmo erro. Não tem nada a ver com o SO. Deve ser algum commit que eu não mandei para o BARE. O fato é que  máquina virtual onde tinha o projeto original já foi deletada.

Comment: Poste o comando de inicialização do repositório bare, versão do Git no host e no guest, etc.

Comment: Outra coisa, o que você está tentando fazer? Ter um repo *bare* na máquina host não faz muito sentido, a não ser que você pretenda dar acesso ssh ou algo do gênero para outras pessoas (e nesse caso provavelmente transformaria o *guest* linux e não o host windows em servidor)

Comment: Eu tenho um ambiente fisico (host) em windows - 1TbSSD. Tenho um disco HD 1Tb como slave do meu SSD. Dentro desse HD tenho uma pasta BARE de repositorio de projetos de estudo, mas que são importantes. Tinha várias MV win7 de teste com algumas configurações diferentes. Quando crio um ambiente novo clono o BARE do HD. Tentei fazer com o linux e nao deu certo. Talvez pq eu tenha deletado a MV win7 (antes de fazer um commit?) que afetou o bare. Nunca pensei que isso fosse ocorrer. Teoricamente eu deveria eu deveria clonar o BARE no seu ultimo estado de commit.

Comment: O comando para criar o git bare foi `$git init --bare "CHM_FINAL_BARE"`.  A versão do git no Linux é `2.7.4`. A versão do git em minha máquina fisica (host) win7 que criou esse repositório bare `2.6.1.windows.1`